# Adverbio o adjetivo con los verbos saber y oler

Tags: adjetivos, adverbios

No me queda claro cuando se usan adverbios y cuando adjetivos con los verbos saber y oler.

Por ejemplo he escuchado:

> La sopa huele **feo**.

(Creo que **feo** no se usa así en todas partes).
En este caso oler se usa con un adverbio. Es similar a decir

> La sopa huele **mal**.

Sin embargo también he escuchado

> La sopa huele **deliciosa**.

En este caso se usa oler más adjetivo.

¿Es correcto que oler se use con adverbios y con adjetivos? ¿Cuándo tengo que usar uno o el otro?

Tengo una duda similar con el verbo saber.

He escuchado:

> El agua de mar sabe **salada**. - adjetivo
> Las espinacas saben **raro**. - adverbio

¿Cuál forma es correcta?

Comment: Pregunta relacionada: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/37378/adverbs-male-vs-female-usage/37379#37379

Answer (score 1):

Ambas formas están aceptadas:

> a) Las espinacas saben **raro**. 
> b) Las espinacas saben **raras**.

En el primer caso se trata de un adverbio adjetival que actúa como complemento circunstancial, mientras que en el segundo es un adjetivo que actúa como complemento predicativo.

Puedes leer más [aquí](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Adverbios%20adjetivales%20o%20cortos.htm)

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta!  Puedes aclarar si las dos versiones tienes exactamente el mismo significativo?
Aplica lo mismo al ejemplo con 'oler' así que uno puede decir o "La sopa huele deliciosa." o "La sopa huele delicioso." y ambas son correctas?

Comment: Por lo visto sí, ambas son correctas ya que el adverbio adjetival "delicioso" puedes convertirlo en "deliciosamente".